# How to build cached tiled services in ArcGIS API JavaScript

Tags: tile-layer

I'm looking for an example or guidance on how to build cached tiled services in ArcGIS API JavaScript. Basically, using layer {z}, row {y}, and column {x} data with my arcgis server. Like this:

https://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Topo_Map/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}

Which results in this: https://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Topo_Map/MapServer/tile/19/220428/141938

I can accomplish this using either OpenLayers or esri with Leaflet.js (samples shown below). I am leaning towards leaflet.js, and I may want to implement both for more advanced work later on, but for now I want to learn how to do this strictly in ArcGIS.

#### OpenLayers sample

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>XYZ Esri</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <!-- The line below is only needed for old environments like Internet Explorer and Android 4.x -->
    <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,URL"></script>
    <script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/build/ol.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <script>
      var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [
          new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.XYZ({
              attributions: 'Tiles © <a href="https://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/' +
                  'rest/services/World_Topo_Map/MapServer">ArcGIS</a>',
              url: 'https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/' +
                  'World_Topo_Map/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}'
            })
          })
        ],
        view: new ol.View({
          center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([-121.1, 47.5]),
          zoom: 7
        })
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

> https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/xyz-esri.html

#### Leaflet.js with Esri  sample

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Simple Leaflet Map</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link 
        rel="stylesheet" 
        href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7/leaflet.css"
    />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 400px"></div>

    <script
        src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7/leaflet.js">
    </script>

    <script>
        var map = L.map('map').setView([-41.2858, 174.78682], 14);
        mapLink = 
            '<a href="http://www.esri.com/">Esri</a>';
        wholink = 
            'i-cubed, USDA, USGS, AEX, GeoEye, Getmapping, Aerogrid, IGN, IGP, UPR-EGP, and the GIS User Community';
        L.tileLayer(
            'http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}', {
            attribution: '&copy; '+mapLink+', '+wholink,
            maxZoom: 18,
            }).addTo(map);

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

> http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/8663620